# Memory Caching in azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, caching, asp.net-web-api, memorycache

I have implemented memory caching in my application and hosted it on azure web application but it is not asynchronous and trying to find ways to fetch the cached data asyncronously.Below is my code

```
strlstInfinity = MemoryCache.Default["InfinityDataCollection"].ToString();
```

The above code is working but not async and tried to put it in a different method and create a Task but it does not work.

Comment: Why do you want to async grab the data, the idea behind the cache is that it is available immediately.

Comment: Erik is right. The data will live in memory, there's no need to make it async.

Comment: @ErikOppedijk when 2 or 3 requests are called the first request takes around 5000 ms where as other request called at the same time takes around 20000 ms so that was why i thought to make it async